# Any form autofill for 'Developers'?

Tags: automation, developer-tools

I have looked at some autofills for Firefox. But they are not designed with the developers' needs in mind. General internet surfers will need a tool to fill in many different forms with constant values for each form. Developers need exactly the opposite, when you want to test a part of your app you'll need to fill a single (or a couple of) forms many times with different (but valid and sensible) data.

So, does such a thing exist? An autofill to fill form inputs based on perhaps a class name (email, password, address, url, ...)?

I strongly feel if it doesn't exist someone should roll up their sleeves and make one! I for one will put in my share if some others want to team up. But right now, I am desperately in need of one if it exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty nice extension for chrome **Web Developer Form Filler** especially for web-developers.
You can save as many sets of data as you want, assign a hotkey and fill a form just by pressing it.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer-form-filler/gbagmkohmhcjgbepncmehejaljoclpil

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use Greasemonkey.

Example script:

- "Auto Fill any forms with custom information":
  http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/39313

EDIT: Link may be broken but I'm sure you are capable of finding many Greasemonkey references.

Comment: It sounds good! in one place it says: `Different profiles (to have real and fake ones)` But at present state it aims the general public, though it may be easy to modify this. I remember I once saw a tool to fill tables in a database with fake but meaningful data (address col with addresses, etc). If the GM script can be married to that, the result will be what I'm looking for. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: The link seems broken at me.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just go with a bookmarklet like https://github.com/dsheiko/autofill
it's a dead simple script that serves me fine for years

Answer (score 2):

Please check out my extension, Form Filler, which allows you to do exactly what you need: fill out your forms with random dummy data.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-filler/bnjjngeaknajbdcgpfkgnonkmififhfo

Answer (score 0):

I think you will love IRobotSoft web automation software.  See a similar question here: 
http://irobotsoft.org/bb/YaBB.pl?num=1254517661

Answer (score -1):

This is an auto form filler you are looking for. But this is a chrome plugin. This takes care of the developers need to fill valid data automatically by reading the properties. It also saves value against the form element if you make changes to it. Hence a must try for developers. Here is the [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-filler/cfghpjmgdnienmgcajbmjjemfnnmldlh?utm_source=gmail)